# how to stop adding input when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want an input to be displayed as a h1 text. It is working but the problem is it keeps adding additional text instead of removing the past added text.

this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var edadUsuario=$('#edadUsuario');
    var edadOtraPersona = $('#edadOtraPersona');
    $('#calcbtn').click(function(){
         var answer = $('#edadUsuario').val();
         $('#answer').append('<h1>' + answer +'</h1>');
    });
});
```

If you need any additional information feel free to ask.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace append with .html() and it should work like a charm.